# Green Theorem in Jackson's Electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, boundary-terms

On Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics page 36, on eq.(1.36), the book derived the Green's theorem:
$$\Phi(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_V \frac{\rho\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)}{R} d^3 x^{\prime}+\frac{1}{4 \pi} \oint_S\left[\frac{1}{R} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n^{\prime}}-\Phi \frac{\partial}{\partial n^{\prime}}\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)\right] d a^{\prime} \tag{1.36}$$
I want to verify that this general potential also satisfy $\nabla^2 \Phi=-\rho / \epsilon_0$, (where we have used this in deriving (1.36)). Which means,
$$\nabla^2 \frac{1}{4 \pi} \oint_S\left[\frac{1}{R} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n^{\prime}}-\Phi \frac{\partial}{\partial n^{\prime}}\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)\right] d a^{\prime}=0  $$
I have tried that (under eq.(1.35))
$$ -\begin{aligned}\nabla^2  \oint_S\left[\frac{1}{R} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n^{\prime}}-\Phi \frac{\partial}{\partial n^{\prime}}\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)\right] d a^{\prime} \end{aligned}\\=\nabla^2 \int_V\left[\Phi \nabla^2 \left(\frac{1}{R}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{R}\right) \nabla^2 \Phi\right] d^3 x\\ =\int_V\left[\Phi \nabla^4 \left(\frac{1}{R}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{R}\right) \nabla^4 \Phi\right] d^3 x$$
My question is how could this equal to zero? Also, in principle, we don't know $\nabla^2 \Phi$ in this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t switch the surface integral back to a volume integral: the whole point of Green’s formula was to use Green’s second identity in order to provide an integral representation for $\Phi(\mathbf{x})$.

Anyway, $\nabla^2\int_S\left[\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial n’}-\Phi\frac{\partial(1/R)}{\partial n’}\right]\,da’$ is zero because once you move the Laplacian inside the integral, it hits the $\frac{1}{R}$ in the first term, and gives $0$ (because $\mathbf{x}\in V$, whereas you’re integrating over the boundary, $\mathbf{x}’\in S$, meaning you’re strictly away from $R=0$, hence the Laplacian vanishes), and when it hits the normal derivative $\frac{\partial (1/R)}{\partial n’}$, you again get $0$ (again, the point $\mathbf{x}$ is strictly away from the boundary surface, so $\frac{1}{R}$ is a perfectly smooth function, so you can commute derivatives). Hence, the Laplacian of the surface integral vanishes.

To show from here that $-\nabla^2\Phi=\rho/\epsilon_0$ you have to be slightly careful with differentiating the volume integral of course, because although $\frac{1}{4\pi R}$ has an integrable singularity in 3-dimensions, its Laplacian in the distributional sense is the Dirac delta. The usual way of proving this is to first remove a small ball $B_{\alpha}(\mathbf{x}_0)$ around the point $\mathbf{x}_0$, do the computation there using the divergence theorem, and then take the limit $\alpha\to 0^+$ (but I guess you’ve already seen this argument ‘in reverse’ when going from $-\nabla^2\Phi=\rho/\epsilon_0$ to the integral formula you quoted).

Comment: Thank you very much! When we move the Laplacian inside the integral, how about $\nabla^2 \Phi$? Would this term also give zero? Thanks!

Comment: @Daren inside the integral $\Phi$ is a function of the primed variable, which is the dummy variable of integration, whereas the Laplacian is with respect to the unprimed $x$. So, as far as the Laplacian is concerned, the $\Phi$ is a 'constant', so it is left unaffected. Tldr: explicitly write out all the arguments of the functions involved to see what needs to be differentiated.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why surface integral vanishes is that when $R$ is chosen such big that the terms with surface integrals have minimum value of $1/R^2$ while terms with volume has maximum value of $1/R$. Now as $R$ increases, surface area become smaller and smaller.

The physical reason is that as $R$ increases, intensity of field decreases quickly as $1/R^2$. When one use integration of surface, the value of field becomes very small at large surfaces.